# Função para mostrar o id dos elementos de uma página em um <span id="span"></span>

Tags: javascript

O javascript deve ser com evento **onmouseover**

```
function mostrarID() {
.........................
.........................
}
document.onmouseover = mostrarID;
```

Exemplo HTML

```
O ID é:"<span id="span" style="font-weight:bold"></span>"<br>
<p id="p1">Paragrafo</p>
<div id="Div1">
<p id="p2">Paragrafo2</p>
<hr id="hr1">
<a href="#" id="Home">Home</a>
</div>
<p id="p3">Paragrafo3</p>
<a href="#" id="nav-questions">Perguntas</a>
<p id="p4">Paragrafo4</p>
<a href="#" id="Tags">Tags</a>

<div id="Div2">
<form id="Form">
<input id="Input" type="text"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta buscar o atributo `id` do elemento em questão com `event.target.getAttribute` e definir o valor no `span` desejado.

```js
const span = document.getElementById("span");

document.onmouseover = function (event) {
  span.innerHTML = event.target.getAttribute("id");
}
```

```html
O ID é:"<span id="span" style="font-weight:bold"></span>"<br>
<p id="p1">Paragrafo</p>
<div id="Div1">
  <p id="p2">Paragrafo2</p>
  <hr id="hr1">
  <a href="#" id="Home">Home</a>
</div>
<p id="p3">Paragrafo3</p>
<a href="#" id="nav-questions">Perguntas</a>
<p id="p4">Paragrafo4</p>
<a href="#" id="Tags">Tags</a>

<div id="Div2">
  <form id="Form">
    <input id="Input" type="text" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Porque só funciona se colocar o script abaixo do html? Eu nunca entendi isso.

Comment: Ordem de execução no navegador. Se colocar antes, o elemento `#span` não existirá no DOM quando `getElementById("span")` for executado, mantendo como `null` a variável `span`. Confirme isso acessando o console do navegador, provavelmente apareceu o erro *Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null* .

Comment: Valeu Anderson Carlos Woss

Comment: Perfeito, testei nos cinco navegadores! Eu estava usando var elem = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)  
 document.all.span.innerText = elem.id porém no firefox não funciona.